# Multiple if condition not working on shopify liqued file

Tags: shopify, liquid

How are you.
I use this code bellow for multiple if condition in shopify liqued file. but it's not working. Please anyone help where I mistake here.

`{%- if product_collection == "Organic and Natural Products" and  product_collection == "Dried Foods" -%} CONTENT HERE A {%- else -%} CONTENT HERE B {%- endif -%}`

Answer (score 1):

The simple explanation is your logic is wrong. A quick example of what I mean:

```
if A is 3 AND A is 5 do something
```

Do you see the problem here? A can NEVER be two things at once. Instead, you probably want the **or** condition. That way, you get choices.

```
if A is 3 OR A is 5 do something
```

Then, your logic will display specific content when either condition for A is true. Otherwise you get the content when neither is true.